# The closure of Infinite set in interval

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, infinity

We endow $\mathbb{R}$ by the natural Topology

Let $E$ be a  an infite  set of $\mathbb{R}$,such that  $E \subset [0, 1]$.

Do we have this property :

As  the cardinal of $E$ is infinite, the closure of $E$ denoted $cl(E)$ is an interval $I$ such that $  cl(E)=I \subseteq [0, 1]$ ?

Any suggestions or references are welcome

Comment: What about $E=\{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ for example

Comment: thanks  @AlessandroCodenotti nice example there exist any properties or references for this kind od set?

Comment: nowhere dense sets are counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cantor set is a compact subset of $[0,1]$ that contains no interval but is uncountable. So no.